# Avoid Clipping when translated into height (supporting different resolution)

Tags: wpf

I'm making an application in which i've used some controls inside Grid Panel. Its working fine but there is a problem for different screen resolution. The Grid controls cannot adapt screen resolution and clip out some control in Height. Whereas width adapt screen resolution correctly. The before and after image is under as you can see when translated into height, cause clipping problem. How to resolve this?

before translated into height:
[image]

after translated into height:
[image]

Code:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF3E7038" Opacity="0.3"/>
                </Grid.Background>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



                <TextBlock Text="Customer:" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10"/>
                <controls:AutoCompleteBox Margin="0,10,10,0" Name="CustomerSearch" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" PreviewKeyDown="CustomerSearch_PreviewKeyDown" >
                    <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:AutoCompleteBox>

                <TextBlock Text="Gross Amount:" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Margin="5,10,0,0"  Name="GrossAmount" Text="0.0" Grid.Column="3" IsReadOnly="True"/>

                <TextBlock Text="Discount%:" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                <TextBox Name="Discount" Text="0.0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" PreviewTextInput="Discount_PreviewTextInput" PreviewKeyDown="Discount_PreviewKeyDown" />

                <TextBlock Text="Net Pay:" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
                <TextBox Name="NetPay" Text="0.0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" PreviewTextInput="Discount_PreviewTextInput" PreviewKeyDown="Discount_PreviewKeyDown" />

                <TextBlock Text="Paid:" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"/>
                <TextBox Name="Paid" Text="0.0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" PreviewTextInput="Paid_PreviewTextInput" PreviewKeyDown="Paid_PreviewKeyDown"/>

                <TextBlock Text="Return:" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"/>
                <TextBox Name="Return" Text="0.0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" IsReadOnly="True"/>

                <WrapPanel Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Button Name="CheckoutBtn"  Margin="0,0,5,0" PreviewKeyDown="CheckoutBtn_PreviewKeyDown" Click="CheckoutBtn_Click" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="40" Height="40" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/checkout.png"/>
                            <Label Content="CHECKOUT" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Name="CancelBtn"  Margin="0,0,5,0"  Click="CancelBtn_Click" >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="40" Height="40" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/cancel.png"/>
                            <Label Content="CANCEL" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>

                    <Button Name="SaveBtn"  Click="SaveBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="40" Height="40" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/save.png"/>
                            <Label Content="SAVE" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>


                </WrapPanel>

            </Grid>
```

Comment: You may want to read about adaptive ui or wrap your controls inside a scrollviewer?

Comment: no, its POINT of Sale software. I dont think ScrollView will be feasable

Comment: Gotcha, then maybe adaptive ui is the solution.

Comment: could you suggest me any reference material

Comment: This should give you an idea on how to achieve it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/xaml-basics-adaptive-layout